# CKEditor not displaying in latest 8.0.x-dev version

Tags: forms, entities, 8, wysiwyg

After updating Drupal from version `8.0.0-beta7` to version `8.0.x-dev` — to fix `text_format` fields not submitting their value due to a missing `name` attribute —, my field is now displaying as a basic `input` field with the format bar under it.

Here's the code that defines the `content` field of my entity (inside the `baseFieldDefinitions` method):

```
$fields['content'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text')
  ->setLabel(t('Content'))
  ->setDescription(t('The content of the block'))
  ->setSettings(array(
    'max_length'  => 1024
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type'   => 'text_format',
    'weight' => -6
  ))
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

As said above, this code works fine on the latest beta but breaks on the latest version from GitHub.

**Expected result (8.0.0-beta7):**

[image]

**Obtained result (8.0.x-dev):**

[image]

I had submitted a [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2447211), thinking this was a bug, but apparently it isn't. I was told I need to use a `textarea` for the editor to show up. The thing is... [`text_format` defaults to a `textarea`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/8#text_format).

I'm guessing there's something I'm not doing right here, but after hours of searching, I just can't seem to understand what. I've tried changing the type passed to `BaseFieldDefinition::create()` to `string_long`, too, but then I just get a `textarea` with no format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code to create a WYSIWYG field:

```
$fields['title'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')
  ->setLabel(t('Content'))
  ->setDescription(t('The content of the block'))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'text_textarea',
    ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      'type' => 'text_default',
    ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Comment: The fix for those fields was to disable ckeditor, because it doesn't support textfields. If you want an editor, use text_long as correctly suggested by the answer. also note that there's no text_format widget, never was, it only works because it falls back to the default.

Comment: I guess I still have a long way to go before fully understanding Drupal. Thanks for the clarification, works like a charm now!